# Send a JSON array via POST request in Flask and cURL

Tags: python, json, curl, flask

I have my app which should accept data from JSON requests and then make some calculations with this data. 
I can get a simple string, but can't accept any arrays (which is extremely important).

```
@app.route('/calc', methods = ['POST'])
def add_entry():
    print("p0")
    request_json = request.get_json()
    cond = request_json.get('condition')
    f_arr = request_json.get('findings')
    return json.dumps(cond, f_arr)

curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"condition\": \"Fibroadenoma\", \"findings\": \"['Mass', 'Special cases']\" }" http://localhost:8080/calc
```

But it doesn't return any array. 
How can I parse it? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two problems. The first is the quoting. The second is that `json.dumps` does not take an arbitrary number of arguments to encode. That is why `f_arr` isn't being returned. I'll update my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

**json.dumps** `json.dumps` takes a single item to encode, not a parameter list of items. If you need to return them both, combine the results into a new list and return that `return json.dumps([cond, f_arr])`

**Quoting**

You are passing a string for findings. Remove the quotes around the list and change the single quotes to escaped double quotes

**edit with explanation**

Let's start off with the data parameter you are passing to curl

```
JoshJ:~ josh$ echo "{ \"condition\": \"Fibroadenoma\", \"findings\": \"['Mass', 'Special cases']\" }"
{ "condition": "Fibroadenoma", "findings": "['Mass', 'Special cases']" }
```

I've used `echo` in my shell to show what the unescaped string looks like

Now let's see what that string looks like when parsed as json

```
JoshJ:~ josh$ echo "{ \"condition\": \"Fibroadenoma\", \"findings\": \"['Mass', 'Special cases']\" }" | jq
{
  "condition": "Fibroadenoma",
  "findings": "['Mass', 'Special cases']"
}
```

This illustrates the issue I mentioned that your `findings` list is actually parsed as a string due to the double quotes. If I were a betting man, I would say that your code is seeing `f_arr == "['Mass', 'Special cases']"` when what you really want is `f_arr = [u"Mass", u"Special cases"]`.

You can correct this by changing your curl data (`-d` value) to `"{ \"condition\": \"Fibroadenoma\", \"findings\": [\"Mass\", \"Special cases\"] }"`.

You can see it is parsed correctly in the example below

```
JoshJ:~ josh$ echo "{ \"condition\": \"Fibroadenoma\", \"findings\": [\"Mass\", \"Special cases\"] }" | jq
{
  "condition": "Fibroadenoma",
  "findings": [
    "Mass",
    "Special cases"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, it simply returns a string for conditions, and that's it. I need to pass an array somehow, because my function accepts an array as an argument later. JSON supports arrays, so how can I send it via request?

Comment: I didn't, and it still doesn't work, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch see my updated answer. Hopefully that explains it